# Unexpected behavior from JMX.newMBeanProxy()

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, mxbean

I get a ThreadMXBean proxy for remote JVM as

```
 ObjectName objName = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getObjectName() ;


  ThreadMXBean proxy = JMX.newMBeanProxy(MBeanServerConnection, objName, ThreadMXBean.class);
```

However, when I call the following, it says it can't convert from `CompositeDataSupport` to `ThreadInfo`.

```
 ThreadInfo tInfo = proxy. getThreadInfo(true, true);
```

Shouldn't the proxy take care of all the conversion? Besides, I'm calling the `getThreadInfo()` on effectively ThreadMXBean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ThreadMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) is an MXBean.  Your code has called [`JMX#newMBeanProxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/JMX.html#newMBeanProxy-javax.management.MBeanServerConnection-javax.management.ObjectName-java.lang.Class-).  The proxy returned by this method is not capable of handling the properties of MXBeans.  Instead, use [`JMX#newMXBeanFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/JMX.html#newMXBeanProxy-javax.management.MBeanServerConnection-javax.management.ObjectName-java.lang.Class-) to obtain a proxy capable of handling the properties of MXBeans.

```
ThreadMXBean proxy = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(MBeanServerConnection, objName, ThreadMXBean.class);
```